# How do you detect key up / key down events from a hardware keyboard on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, keyboard

While there are many methods posted on SO regarding hacking keyboards to work, for example, [How can I support the up and down arrow keys with a Bluetooth keyboard under iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235762/how-can-i-support-the-up-and-down-arrow-keys-with-a-bluetooth-keyboard-under-ios), or [Receive iPhone keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267560/receive-iphone-keyboard-events/8862814#8862814), none of them are documented.

Is it possible to detect a keyUp: / keyDown: input event from a hardware keyboard (e.g. bluetooth) in iOS using public APIs?

Comment: Are you asking about framework capabilities, App Store approval, developer sentiment, or what?

Comment: If you need a definitive answer from Apple, you could build a sample project and raise a TSI: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/submit/

Comment: Removed vitriol in response to @user2864740, I am not looking for a holy war, merely a method of detecting basic keyboard input *in a way that is viable for commercial deployment*.

Comment: Good edit. I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: @RoboticCat, as a newbie to iOS development, I appreciate this pointer, and may wind up taking this route, though from a legalese standpoint it would be easy to discard my code as merely 'undocumented'.  I hope that any answer Apple give would be definitive, and useful for other people who stumble across this problem, (those porting QT, GTK, SDL or similar toolkits)

Comment: @Justin app store approval- I am porting an in-house toolkit to iOS, but I want to be able to look a client in the eye and say "yes, your app won't randomly disappear because I did something naughty that Apple didn't like."  There is, afaict, no guidance in this area.

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible, which is ridiculous. See also my comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235762/how-can-i-support-the-up-and-down-arrow-keys-with-a-bluetooth-keyboard-under-ios .

Comment: This is a good question and I'm looking for an answer too. Detecting key up / key down state if very important if you want to develop an action game on iOS with bluetooth keyboard support. For example, press on arrow keys to manoeuvre a spaceship or press down Enter key to fire. No game players want to play the game by tediously click (press and release) those keys.

Comment: This is an excellent use case that I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of iOS 13.4, this is now possible due to the introduction of [`UIKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipress/3526315-key), which is included on [`pressesBegan`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621134-pressesbegan) events now when a keyboard key is pressed. [this guide](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/handling-keyup-and-keydown-events/) from Swift By Sundell covers some examples. Here is the relevant bit:

```
class EditorViewController: UIViewController {
    ...

    override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>,
                               with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
        presses.first?.key.map(keyPressed)
    }

    override func pressesEnded(_ presses: Set<UIPress>,
                               with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        super.pressesEnded(presses, with: event)
        presses.first?.key.map(keyReleased)
    }

    override func pressesCancelled(_ presses: Set<UIPress>,
                                   with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        super.pressesCancelled(presses, with: event)
        presses.first?.key.map(keyReleased)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add a check for older iOS versions or is this handled by iOS SDK?

Comment: @MrStahlfelge I just tested with iOS 13.2 and it worked without anything special. lower iOS versions just never include `UIKey` values in the UIPress objects.