# Recognise events from an external accessory in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, bluetooth

I have a Logitech R500 connected to an iPad via Bluetooth. When I open keynotes for example, it works.
Is it possible to get events from this device in my own app using Swift?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083400/how-do-you-detect-key-up-key-down-events-from-a-hardware-keyboard-on-ios) is probably what you need. The device is probably just an external keyboard as far as iOS is concerned.

Comment: Yes that is exactly it, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you detect key up / key down events from a hardware keyboard on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083400/how-do-you-detect-key-up-key-down-events-from-a-hardware-keyboard-on-ios)